# How to create sub-labels for input elements using HTML

Tags: html, css, input, label

I am using windows to create a simple HTML form, and I cannot figure out how to create the sub-labels for the various inputs. The picture (link in comment below) shows what I am trying to produce. Is this a Safari only thing? The closest I came was using CSS display:block which allowed me to move the label on top of the input.

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/3v81s2adj/formslabel.png

Comment: by sub label do you mean you want the text to go in the box and then vanish when the user clicks the box?

Comment: No, outside the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that by wrapping each group of label & input within e.g. div, like so:

```
<div class="form-line">
   <div class="form-field">
      <input class="form-field-input" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Your value..." />
      <label class="form-field-label" for="input1">
         Text 1
      </label>
   </div>
   <!-- other groups go here -->
</div>
```

Here's the CodePen [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpJsD)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'd need something like

```
<input type='name' class='my-input'>
<label for="name">
    <span class="label">First</span>
</label>
```

and then style that.